# Get the number of subset.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

number of subsets of A with an even number of elements;

A ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

I have no idea about this question(This is part h of the problem set and I finished the previous). Here, subsets of A with an even number of elements should look like {1,2,3} or {1,2,3,4} and etc. obviously. Can I simply get the number all the subset of {1,3,5,7} and multiply the result by seven since there are 6 possible cases for have even number(2,4,6,24,26,46,246). But I think this will be involved into counting some subset more than once.

I was a little confused by the answers but thank you all. So can anyone point out what is wrong with my solution?

for a subset with an (means at least one) even number, I firstly compute the number of subset of {1,3,5,7}, it should be 16. And for each subset, I add an even number in A to them first, get 16*3 subsets. Then add two even number, for example add 2,4 into {1,3} then get {1,2,3,4}. By doing this I get 16*3, and last, add 2,4,6 into all subsets of {1,3,5,7}, get 16 more, totolly 7*16 subsets contain at least one even number.

Note: It's not even subset, I mean subset with even elements.

Thank you all again

Comment: The set $\{1,2,3\}$ has an odd number of elements (namely 3).

Comment: You _don't_ want subsets containing an element that is an even number.  You want subsets with _an even number of elements_.  So it's the size of the subset that matters.

Comment: If you mean subsets containing even elements, you should write that; "subsets with an even number of elements" means, unambiguously, "subsets whose number of elements is even".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider the function $B\mapsto A\setminus B$. If $B$ has an odd number of elements, how many elements does $A\setminus B$ have? Show that it is a bijection, and conclude the correct number.

Answer (score 2):

You need to work out the number of ways of choosing subsets of size 0,2,4,6.

Ways of choosing size 0: ${7 \choose 0}$

Ways of choosing size 2: ${7 \choose 2}$

Ways of choosing size 4: ${7 \choose 4}$

Ways of choosing size 6: ${7 \choose 6}$.

Compute these values and add them up.

Comment: you should also add  $7\choose 0$

Comment: Yes, thanks. :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: So the answer is 102?

Comment: If that's what the calculator says!

Comment: @SonicFancy: 1+21+35+7=64

Comment: And how would you solve this if instead of seven elements you are given $301$ elements? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: answer is $2^{300}$.

Comment: Personally I would work out the general form of the sum. Fortunately we weren't asked this.

Comment: @mesel: Yes, I know. In fact, that's why I find my answer to be the "correct one", because it's a general argument why this is always $2^{|A|-1}$, rather than a particular counting argument for $|A|=7$.

Comment: I was a little confused by the answers but thank you all. So can anyone point out what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, then again, there is correct, and there is appropriate. If a student is being asked this sort of question I don't think that level of sophistication is appropriate.

Comment: @SonicFancy If you know how to work out ${n \choose k}$ for given $n$ and $k$ and you followed the recipe above, the only explanation is that you made an arithmetical mistake.

Comment: @Frank: I agree with the first sentence, not with the second. If a teacher is asking this question, it's so the strong students can come up with a general method, and the weak students could still solve by counting manually the particular case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree with you entirely; but then if someone is struggling and has to post the question here, can we not safely assume that the brute-force method is appropriate?

Comment: @AsafKaragila:If someone is asking about Pythagoras theorem no need to give him cosine theorem to confuse him.

Comment: @Frank: No, we shouldn't safely assume that. My experience says that often taking a step back from counting manually, and trying to understand a general argument can be much easier. The reason is simple, you're not lost in a sea of particular numbers and sets.

Comment: OK I got it... My misunderstanding makes me confused.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, but then you are a set theory PhD student. Some discrimination based on who your audience is is obviously important. Who knows... SonicFancy could be 15 years old, in which case he would have no idea what a bijection is.

Comment: @Frank: I also have an experience as a teacher, not just as a student. Both freshmen and seniors (and some grad students too), as well strong and weak students.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I definitely didn't mean to cause offence or question your personal qualifications, so sorry if you felt attacked; but it is a very interesting debate, without an obvious 'answer' :)

Comment: @Frank: I didn't feel offended or attacked at any point. It was not my intention to come across as defensive...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Good, then we are both happy! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is 1 subset with no elements (the empty set).

There are 7 subsets with seven elements.  $\{1\}, \{2\}, \ldots \{7\}$

There are $7 \choose 2$ subsets with 2 elements, and $7 \choose 3$ with three elements, et cetera.  Choosing a number if elements from the superset using the binomial term.

So the total of even subsets is is $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{3} {7 \choose 2k} ={7\choose 0}+{7\choose 2}+{7\choose 4}+{7\choose 6} = 64$$

Comment: where are you + signs?

Comment: I was a little confused by the answers but thank you all. So can anyone point out what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: @SonicFancy, you were trying to count the wrong things.  You wanted subsets with _an even number of elements_, not containing an even numbered element.

Answer (score 0):

Say you are to count the number of subsets with an even number of elements taken of $\mathcal{A}$ with $n$ elements. If $\mathcal{A}$ has an odd number of elements, each time you pick a subset with an even number of elements, what is left over is a subset with an odd number of elements, and the other way around. So the number of even sized subsets and the number of odd sized subsets are the same, half the number of all subsets of $\mathcal{A}$, i.e., $2^{n - 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is subsets with at least one *even element*.

You have 4 odd elements, of them you can create $2^4 = 16$ subsets in all. You also have 3 even elements, out of them you have a total of $2^3 = 8$ subsets, but you have to exclude the empty set, leaving $2^3 - 1$. To create the sets you are interested in, you combine any set of odd elements with a non-empty set of even elements, in all $2^4 \cdot (2^3 - 1) = 112$ sets.